# Error on install hoauth extension for Yii

Tags: oauth, yii

I'm trying to install this extension: https://github.com/SleepWalker/hoauth/wiki/%5Binstall%5D-hoauth-and-yii-user-extension.

I follow the instruction and get the error: "Alias "ext.hoauth.HOAuthAdminAction" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable" when access the user/login/oauthadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by chmod:

```
chmod 755 hoauth -R
```

Comment: Yeah, it relates with the directory permission. Everything seems right until I find out that the web user can't access the parent directory of hoauth. Just simple "chown" to add the web user and it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You have placed hoauth extension in wrong directory.

```
print_r(Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext'));
print_r(Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.hoauth'));
print_r(Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.hoauth.HOAuthAdminAction'));
```

Check the right path to your extension

[More about Path Alias and Namespace in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace)

Answer (score 0):

i too had this problem, but in my case the hoauth extension which is in extensions directory having the different name(its having hoauth-master).so i removed the -master and put the name as hoauth, then it is working. So once check your directory name too.hope it helps.